# Write into mongodb after processing files

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Say, I have 10,000 files and I'm going to use python code to extract some information from these files and write these information into mongodb. All of these operations will be done in a single local computer.

Will I be able to use python's multiprocessing package to do all the operations in parallel to speed things up? Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, multiprocessing will help distribute the workload. If you have, say, 8 cores on your machine, then roughly 8 Python processes will probably maximize throughput. More than that, and contention on disk I/O, or competition with the MongoDB server for CPU time, will become a bottleneck. The "multiprocessing.Pool.map" function is particularly elegant for dividing work among processes:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers

Comment: Thanks! I was worrying there would be problem if multiple processes try to write into the same collection in MongoDB.

Comment: MongoDB's thread-safe, you can write concurrently from many connections.